# Stein's real variables, chapter 6 , Exercise 9

Tags: measure-theory

Let $C([a, b])$ be a space of continuous function on the closed, bounded interval $[a, b]$. Let $µ$ be a Borel measure, such that $µ([a, b]) < ∞$. Then

$$ f → l(f)=\int  f d\mu (x)$$ is a linear functional on C([a, b]), with $l$ positive in the sense that $l(f) ≥ 0$ if $f ≥ 0$. 
Prove that, conversely, for any linear functional $l$ on $C([a, b])$ that is positive, there is a unique Borel measure $\mu$ so that $l(f) =\int  f d\mu$  for all $f ∈ C([a, b])$.

There is a hint in the book:

Define $F(u) = lim(ε→0)⁡l(fε)$, 
where $fε(x) = 1$, if $x ∈ [0, u]$, $fε(x) = 0$, if$ x ∈ [u + ε, 1]$
and connected by a linear segment for $x ∈ [u, u + ε]$.

How can I prove $ F $ is increasing , right-continuous and $l(f)$ can be written as $\int  f dF$.

I am really stuck...any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: It is The Riesz-Markov Theorem, but how to prove it using the hint.